# How do I update swift tools version?

Tags: swift, docker, dockerfile

I am following a server side swift tutorial and I am currently trying to dockerize my project.
when running the command `docker run -v $PWD:/swift-project -w /swift-project server-build /swift-utils/tools-utils.sh build release` to run the build image and Im getting the following error:

`/swift-project: error: package at '/swift-project' is using Swift tools version 5.2.0 but the installed version is 5.0.0`

If I wanted to keep the swift-tools-version at 5.2 in my Package.swift, how would I update from version 5.0 to 5.2?

Comment: Do you have a sample of your Dockerfile?